# Mongoose find problem - TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having a issue with a mongoose find() query, which I cannot figure out.  the error I receive is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined" which I suspect is an export/import problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my scheme model file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  pageGroup: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true,
  },
  level: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true,
  }
})

const OfficeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  officeId: { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: "Office",
    required: true,
  },
  roleId: { 
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
    required: false,
  },
})

const InstanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  instanceId: { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: "Instance",
    required: true,
  },
  offices: { 
    type: [OfficeSchema], 
    required: false,
  },
})

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      firstName: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
      },
      lastName: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
      },
      email: { 
        type: String, 
        required: false 
      },
      password: { 
        type: String, 
        required: false 
      },
      access: {
        type: [InstanceSchema], 
        required: false,
      }, 
      permissions: {
        type: [RoleSchema], 
        required: false,
      },
      activationToken: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
      },
      roleId: { // new
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          // index: true,
          ref: 'Role',
          // default: null
      },
      employeeId: {
          type: String, 
          required: false 
      },
      instanceId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'Instance', 
          required: true 
      },
      officeId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'Office', 
          required: true 
      }, 
    }, 
    {
      toJSON: { virtuals: true },
      toObject: { virtuals: true },
    })

UserSchema.virtual('instances', {
  ref: 'Instance',
  localField: 'access.instanceId',
  foreignField: '_id',
});

UserSchema.virtual('instances.offices', {
  ref: 'Office',
  localField: 'access.offices.officeId',
  foreignField: '_id',
});

UserSchema.virtual('office', {
  ref: 'Office',
  localField: 'officeId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
});

UserSchema.virtual('name').get(function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = { User }
```

here is my function in my controller file:

```
const { User } = require('./user.model');

async getEmployees(){
    
    const employees = await User.find({
            instanceId: this._id,
        }, '-password -activationToken -__v -activated')
        .populate('office')
        .sort([['firstName', 1]])
        .exec()

    return employees
},
```

Comment: Smells like a cyclic dependency, but there isn't one in the code you're showing (if it _is_, moving the `require()` to inside `getEmployees` may work, as a quick hack).

Comment: You are correct! it was a cyclic dependency. Moving inside the getEmployees function did the trick. Thank you very much sir! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error points to `User` being undefined, which can happen when your project has [cyclic dependencies](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles) (where file A.js depends on file B.js, which in turn depends on file A.js again, either directly or indirectly through another file).

A quick fix is to delay loading the `User` model until the moment it's actually needed, by moving the `require()` into `getEmployees()`:

```
async getEmployees(){
    const { User } = require('./user.model');
    
    const employees = await User.find({
            instanceId: this._id,
        }, '-password -activationToken -__v -activated')
        .populate('office')
        .sort([['firstName', 1]])
        .exec()

    return employees
}
```

But ideally, you should get rid of the cyclic dependency altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my project. You can fix it by replacing

```
const { User } = require('./user.model');
```

of your controller by :

```
const User = require('./user.model');
```

Just by removing the brackets made it for me. So I guess you should use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).